# Eclipselink attempts to covert UUID to byte[] on MSSQL

Tags: java, sql-server, jpa, eclipselink, uuid

I have my entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TABLE")
public class User {

    @Id
    @Column
    private UUID id;
```

I'm using EclipseLink. When I try to execute the following code:

```
em.createQuery("select t from Table").getResultList();
```

I got exception:

> Caused by: org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ConversionException: 
>   Exception Description: The object
>   [9ABCC78A-4C58-41D2-A672-324F6B095260], of class [class
>   java.lang.String], could not be converted to [class [B].  at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ConversionException.couldNotBeConverted(ConversionException.java:78)
>   ~[?:?]    at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.helper.Helper.buildBytesFromHexString(Helper.java:266)
>   ~[?:?]    at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.helper.ConversionManager.convertObjectToByteArray(ConversionManager.java:326)
>   ~[?:?]    at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.helper.ConversionManager.convertObject(ConversionManager.java:138)
>   ~[?:?]    at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatasourcePlatform.convertObject(DatasourcePlatform.java:179)
>   ~[?:?]    at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.extractPrimaryKeyFromRow(ObjectBuilder.java:3104)
>   ~[?:?]    at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildObject(ObjectBuilder.java:705)
>   ~[?:?]    at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildObject(ObjectBuilder.java:689)
>   ~[?:?]    at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.buildObject(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:805)
>   ~[?:?]    at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.registerResultInUnitOfWork(ReadAllQuery.java:962)
>   ~[?:?]    at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.executeObjectLevelReadQuery(ReadAllQuery.java:573)
>   ~[?:?]    at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1175)
>   ~[?:?]    at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:904)
>   ~[?:?]    at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.execute(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1134)
>   ~[?:?]    at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.execute(ReadAllQuery.java:460)
>   ~[?:?]    at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1222)
>   ~[?:?]    at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2896)
>   ~[?:?]    at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1857)
>   ~[?:?]    at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1839)
>   ~[?:?]    at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1804)
>   ~[?:?]    at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.executeReadQuery(QueryImpl.java:258)
>   ~[?:?]    at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:473)
>   ~[?:?]    ... 61 more

I have tried to add `AttributeConverter<UUID, String>` in orm.xml, but I get the same exception

```
<converter class="com.example.UuidConverter" auto-appy="true"/>
```

The 'trick' in converter works fine with PostgreSQL (I need there `AttributeConverter<UUID, UUID>`, because JDBC driver returns UUID), but on MSSQL, I've failed to find the working solution.

How to handle that case so that my entity would support also MSSQL?

Comment: From the looks of the stack trace, the ORM converter wasn't picked up and the ID is being processed as if it were a lob.  Does the issue still occur if you add the converter through annotations?

Comment: @Chris annotations are tabu for me because I want the same class to work for PostgreSQL, but I've tried with registering converter per field through my orm.xml, and it seems to work, so it looks like the converter wasn't picked by default. Thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

There is a trick, I hope this help some else with the same problem

Step #1 Create a class converter

```
import org.eclipse.persistence.internal.helper.DatabaseField;
import org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.DatabaseMapping;
import org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.DirectCollectionMapping;
import org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.converters.Converter;
import org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.Session;

import java.util.UUID;

public class MyUUIDConverter implements Converter {

    @Override
    public Object convertObjectValueToDataValue(Object o, Session session) {
        return o;
    }

    @Override
    public UUID convertDataValueToObjectValue(Object o, Session session) {
        return (UUID) o;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isMutable() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(DatabaseMapping databaseMapping, Session session) {

        final DatabaseField field;

        if (databaseMapping instanceof DirectCollectionMapping) {

            // handle @ElementCollection...

            field = ((DirectCollectionMapping) databaseMapping).getDirectField();

        } else {

            field = databaseMapping.getField();

        }

        field.setSqlType(java.sql.Types.OTHER);

        field.setTypeName("java.util.UUID");

        field.setColumnDefinition("your column name in database");

    }
}
```

Step #2 Use annotation Converter to implement your class recently created

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TABLE")
@Converter(name = "myUuidConverter", converterClass = MyUUIDConverter.class)
public class User {
```

Step #3 USe Annotation Convert in your property

```
@Convert("myUuidConverter")
  private UUID id;
```